# How would you allow users to query your database using SQL syntax or a SQL-like syntax?

Tags: sql

How would you design a system that allow peoples to create "SQL queries" that are used to extract informations from your sites.

I am thinking about https://data.stackexchange.com/ or http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/

Also, what precaution must be used to avoid/reduce security issues.

Thank you

Comment: You could allow generic SQL statements but grant only `select` permissions to the account being used to execute the queries.

Comment: @meagar, creating a public user with only `select`'s permisions. That is what I thought too. But, are there any command that must also be filtered that may cause security issue if they aren't ?

Comment: @meager, that would provide read only access, which is not the same thing as secure access.

Comment: @mikerobi, I believe that the two links I provided are read-only's systems. That is perfect but I would like to allow the user to create temporary tables.

Answer (score 0):

Something worth looking into would be http://www.odata.org/, this is slightly different but could allow you to query the database from the url without building querystring parameters yourself.

Comment: Great stuff. I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

To keep information secure, you would need:

- A role-based system where certain levels cannot:

  1. Execute some statements ("DROP",DELETE","JOIN",etc)
  2. display some rows (passwords,other sensitive info)

Comment: The point 2 must require some parsing so the users can't retreive sensitive columns or tables. Is there an easy way to do that?